# reflow, renderContents, createComponents in Ares for webOS

Tags: webos, palm

I need programmatic access to the chrome files that Ares uses to paint the DOM tree and the lack of documentation on how to access it is very frustrating. I'm building some apps that need to be a little dynamic in how they handle the DOM tree and Ares has no documentation on how it takes the chrome files and turns them into DOM elements. Does anyone have any good references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very sparse documentation for Ares, it won't hurt to try and get a response from Palm on developer.palm.com.

Your best bet may be to download the source from Ares and import into Eclipse for this project.  Otherwise you may spend more time reverse-engineering rather than developing.